# Get windows disk number using the filesystem label

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I can use `Get-Volume` to acquire a list of drive names which i need to access, but this does not associate the drive name to a drive number, such as when you do `Get-Disk`. `Get-Disk` however does not list the filesystemlabel.

What I am trying to do is:

`Add-Partitionaccesspath` cmdlet for a drive based on its name. This seems to be done most easily with a disk number and the path. I tried `Add-Partitionaccosspath -UniqueID` with the drives name, but then was asked for an offset which I am unfamiliar with. Is there anyway to associate the drive filesystem label, for example "SSD" or "HDD" to the physical drive number so that I could then run the partitionaccesspath with just the drive number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually chain the cmdlets you mentioned if you also take `Get-Partition` into account.

```
Get-Volume | where DriveLetter -eq "C" | Get-Partition | Get-Disk
```

That way you would get the drive for a given volume.

If you look at the [help for `Add-ParitionAccessPath`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh848703(v=wps.630).aspx), you will find that there is no `UniqueId` parameter but the `DiskId` parameter set is able to use an `Offset`. Though I wonder why you would not just use the `DriveLetter` parameter set as you would only need to call `Get-Volume` to have all the information.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the drive labeling is outside of my control. The Disks fileystemlabels will be known ahead of time, but that is all.This works perfectly for what I am doing though. Thanks for helping out a powershell noob!